# How to ensure FTPeS uses a secure connection?

Tags: ftp

From: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/FTPS

> **Explicit:** 
> If a client does not request security, the FTPS server can either allow the client to continue insecure or refuse/limit the connection.
>
> **Implicit:** 
> A client is immediately expected to challenge the FTPS server with a TLS/SSL ClientHello message. If such a message is not received by the FTPS server, the server should drop the connection.

So If I own only the client side, then what can I do to allow an FTPES connection to **only use** a secure connection? Under a non-windows OS.

IPtables/pf rule? Proxy? or What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to configure the client to always use encrypted control and data connections. For example, in [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) this is done by setting `ftp:ssl-force` and `ftp:ssl-protect-data` to `true`.